# Excel: Output values from one column into one cell separated by semicolon

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with one hundred rows. I have one column with a value in each cell.

For Example:

ABC

TRE

TED

CAR

I want an output that has all the values in one cell separated by a semicolon.

Any idea how to do this? I am new in Excel.

Output all in a single cell:
ABC; TRE; TED; CAR;

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are in cells A1, B1, C1 and D1 and your output formula for instance is E1 then use formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,";",A2,";",A3,";",A4)
```

Comment: I have one hundred rows. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Apollo look at your question, if you have a 100 rows please edit your post. In that case using VBA will be the more elegant way to go, so change the TAG as well

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (using the cells from the previous answer) you can try:

```
  =A1&";"&B1&";"&C1&";"&D1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If anyone needs it. This writes to the first cell in the B column after it has been stored in the total variable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long

Set r = Range("A1:A118")
Dim total As String


mynumber = 0
For Each cell In r
    mynumber = mynumber + 1
   total = total + cell.Value + ";"
Next

Cells(1, 2) = total

End Sub
```